# UITapGestureRecognizer work by default on UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my code by default work UITapGesture how to remove this

NSString *dirString;

host is class object

```
-(Void) handleSwipeEvent : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

//NSString *swipeDirection = NULL;
//CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self];
dirString = NULL;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=nil;
tap.enabled=NO;
if ([recognizer direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    dirString = kCATransitionFromRight;

}

if ([recognizer direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
    dirString = kCATransitionFromLeft;
}

if (dirString) [host swipeTo:dirString];


} 
-(void)createSwipeGestureRecognizer:(UIView *)view direction:  (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)direction
{

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeEvent:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer setDirection:direction];
[self setSwipeRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

}

- (void) setHost: (FlashCardViewController *) aHost {

host = aHost;
[self createSwipeGestureRecognizer:self direction:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self createSwipeGestureRecognizer:self direction:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

}
```

On the view i have to touch then load next contant.
How can i disable tap event

Comment: Do you mean you also have UITapGestureRecognizer added in this class?

Comment: No I dont want. In this class by default work UITapGesture I am not implementing this functionality.